# how to get an entity By a related object id when using spring data neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

```
@NodeEntity    
public class Person {
  @GraphId private Long nodeId;
  private String name;
  private String addr;
  private int age;

  @Relationship(type="WATCH")
  private Set<Movie> movies;
}


@NodeEntity
public class Movie{
  @GraphId private Long nodeId;
  private String title;
  private int released;


  @Relationship(type="WATCH" ,direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
  private Person person;

  public Movie(){}
}


@RequestMapping(value = "/movieTest", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Movie movieTest(){
    Movie movie =movieRepository.findOne(5078L,1);
    return movie;
}
public interface MovieRepository extends GraphRepository<Movie> {
}
```

I create a Person class and a Movie class ,Person "WATCH" Movie,Person has property "movies",and Movie has property "person",My purpose is to get Person by a movie id,but an "java.lang.StackOverflowError" exception happened when I call /movieTest API,because after findOne() executed , the result object movie has a sub-object person, and person has a sub-object movies ,then go to a endless loop,
   so what I wonder is how to deal this situation or what should I do when I need to get Person By a movie id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly we need to double check the model. In Cypher you are saying `(:Person)-[:WATCH]->(:Movie)`.  In your java code you are saying:

1. A person can watch many movies:
2. A movie can be watched by one person.

In general a movie could be watched by many people though right? If that's the case the movie class should hold a collection of people (with the same mapping).

If it's some sort of movie preview app where exactly `0..1` `Person`s can watch a movie and once it's watched no one else can watch it (or it gets updated so the last person who watched it is the person) then you have several options:

1. You could add a custom query to your repository:

   ```
   public interface PersonRepository extends GraphRepository<Person> {
       @Query("MATCH (n:Person)-[r]->(m:Movie) WHERE ID(m) = {movieId} RETURN r")
       Person findByMovieId(@Param("movieId) Long id);
   }
   ```

   Returning the relationship means your person object should get hydrated with the watched movie.
2. Simply retrieve the movie as you are with the `findOne` method and then get the person from it: `movie.getPerson()`